# My Cycles render Display wrong image

Tags: cycles-render-engine

[image]

My Cycles display mode didnt project the object correctly
Am new to blender and this is the first time it happen
pls help

Comment: hello, it's hard to understand what's happening and what you mean, could you please share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Looks like you have a displacement map that translates one of the objects along Z axis

Comment: https://pasteall.org/blend/92c24b2606224ddd846864a6449f28f1
this is the file

Comment: Left pic is render preview and right is material preview
See the outer circle of my object shouldnt cross with my inner circle

Comment: I do everything again with the same way i do before but now it didnt have the same problem so i will end this now